# Is file system one of the NoSQL? What's the main difference?

Tags: database, nosql

I am confused about it.

I can use lucene to create index and run query against file system.
I can find any particular file very fast, if I can provide a primary key, in this case, directory path and filename act as primary key.

It looks very much like a NoSQL.

Comment: If a database doesn't store its data in memory then where else other than the file system would it be stored?

Comment: Are you asking if the file system is a type of NoSQL?

Comment: I am kinda confused. Should File System be considered as database?

Comment: I've seen systems that used PostgeSQL as a database of large images (potentially gigabytes each), but kept the files in the filesystem. In a sense, the filesystem was functioning as a database, but I don't think that usage is typical.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A (Unix) file system is a hierarchical database for unstructured untyped data. The  BeFS is more like a metadata-addressable graph of semi-structured data. The VMS filesystem is a hierarchical database for semi-structured versioned data. The OS/400 filesystem is actually pretty close to SQL in its semantics. Different filesystems are very different!

NoSQL is a movement that advocates choosing the best-fitting database technology for your data model. (NoSQL == Not Only SQL)

If you have tree-shaped unstructured data, then storing it in the (Unix) filesystem definitely fits the goals of the NoSQL movement. If your data however is relational, then choosing the filesystem is actually exactly the *opposite* of NoSQL: remember, NoSQL means choosing the best-fitting database technology for your data model, and if your data is relational, then that model is SQL.